# Provide template with expressions as attribute on directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm wanting to pass a "template" into a directive, by means of an attribute. Here's a trite example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

This HTML:

```
<greeter person-name="Jim" greeting-template="Hello {{name}}"></greeter>
```

Would produce output: `Hello Jim`.

I've tried with a directive like this:

```
function greeter($interpolate) {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div>{{evaluatedTemplate}}</div>'
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.name = attrs.personName;
        scope.evaluatedTemplate = $interpolate(attrs.greetingTemplate)(scope);
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work, because `{{name}}` in the `greeting-template` attribute gets evaluated in the parent scope before it gets as far as the directive link function.

Ultimately, I would need the value of `attrs.greetingTemplate` to *literally* be a string of: 'Hello {{name}}'. I figure I could do it with some alternative syntax, like having the `greeting-template` attribute value as: "Hello [name]" and convert "[" to "{{" before interpolation. But that feels messy. I looked at transclusion too, but the way it evaluates the directive against the *parent* scope looks like it could cause issues when I have multiple greeter's.

Comment: Maybe try https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable

Comment: Setting `ng-non-bindable` attribute on the `greeter` element not only prevents the `greeting-template` attribute from being Angular evaluated (good), it also prevents the entire directive from being evaluated (bad). So that's not the answer.

Comment: Use different braces in html instead of `{{}}` and parse them yourself. Or use an options object and pass that in from controller

Comment: Poking around on the other objects passed to the `link` function, I've found that `element.attr('greeting-template')` returns 'Hello {{name}}'. This is exactly what I'm looking for. But without a more complete understanding of the object, I'm wary of whether there might be any edge cases I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `link` function, you could use the `compile` function, which runs before any linking to a scope occurs, and gets passed the template element (the original DOM element) as well as its uninterpolated attributes as arguments. I think that's what you're looking for here.

In the `compile` function, you could store the uninterpolated template string in a variable for later use in your `post-link` function (which is the same as the `link` function if you use `link` rather than `compile`), where you can then bind it to your scope.

So your directive would look like this, with a `compile` property rather than a `link` property:

```
function greeter($interpolate) {
  var directive = {
    compile: compile,
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: true,
    template: '<div>{{evaluatedTemplate}}</div>'
  };
  return directive;

  function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {

    // save the uninterpolated template for use in our post-link function
    var greetingTemplateUninterpolated = tAttrs.greetingTemplate;

    return {
      pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {},
      post: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.name = attrs.personName;
        scope.evaluatedTemplate = $interpolate(greetingTemplateUninterpolated)(scope);
      }
    };
  }  
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skxh2gd5/) showing it working.

And [here's](http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/) a really good article explaining how `compile` and `link` work.

Comment: Great! If I could suggest just one change, it's better with its own scope, either prototypally inherited or isolated. I've recommended an edit for `scope: true`.

Comment: I completely agree. That was my thought also, but since it wasn't in your original directive, I didn't want to just add it without knowing if you had a specific reason for leaving it out.